# ActiveRecord: Recursive relationships?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I want User's to be able to like, and be liked by, other users. What's the best Railsy way to set this up?

I envision a user table:

```
Like
----
belongs_to :user
belongs_to :likeable, polymorphic: true

User
----
has_many :likes, as: :likeable
```

????

Not quite sure how to setup the relationship from there. Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11947556/3797480) is an answer already provided for you. [Here](https://github.com/ryanto/acts_as_votable) is a popular gem for what you are doing. [Here](http://railscasts.com/episodes/163-self-referential-association) is nice railscast about self referential association.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you would use a polymorphic table for this but I am new to rails.  I would just use a self join table.  User has many likes.  like belongs to user.  like has 2 columns both of which are references to the users table.   There may be a better way to do this as my name suggests I am a newbie.